# If $\alpha \in (0,1)$ is an irrational number, show that $\alpha = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{q_{n+1}q_{n}}$

Tags: convergence-divergence, summation, continued-fractions

If $\alpha \in (0,1)$ is an irrational number, the question is to show that

\begin{equation}
\alpha = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{q_nq_{n-1}}
\end{equation}

(where $q_n$ denotes the denominator of the n$^{th}$ partial quotient of $\alpha$).

What I have tried to use is that if:

\begin{equation}
p_nq_{n-1} - q_np_{n-1} = (-1)^{n+1}\\
\frac{p_nq_{n-1}}{q_n} - p_{n-1} = \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{q_n}\\
\frac{p_n}{q_n} - \frac{p_{n-1}}{q_{n-1}} = \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{q_nq_{n-1}}\\
\end{equation}

Since, by definition, $\alpha = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{p_n}{q_n}$, it looks like it could be a telescopic series using what I have calculated. Does anyone know if I'm on the right track here?

Update: For example, if I re-write the equation above;

\begin{equation}
\frac{p_n}{q_n} = \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{q_nq_{n-1}} + \frac{p_{n-1}}{p_{n-1}}\\
\frac{p_n}{q_n} = \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{q_nq_{n-1}} + \frac{(-1)^n}{q_{n-1}q_{n-2}} + \frac{p_{n-2}}{q_{n-3}}\\
\end{equation}

Comment: Yes,you are on the right track.Now, you can take the summation of both sides (justify that you can do so, of course), and you  should be done.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Thank you for this post. I actually don't know this result.

Comment: What you have is called the [Euler-Minding series](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=R8LkjJxor2EC&pg=PA7).